# Bezier curve won't join?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, edit-mode

[image: curve in edit mode]

I am making a track for Assetto Corsa using curves. Basically I am having a problem here with this bezier curve (cyan arrow). I want to join it with the control handle marked in yellow.
Tried <kbd>C</kbd> but that highlights vertices and <kbd>F</kbd> won't close it.

Comment: you have a hidden control point unhide all with Alt+H and select the two then click F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last control point on one end is hidden, in edit mode  :

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show all hidden points
- Select the two end control points and hit <kbd>F</kbd>